# Wordpress - Pull posts from category via Ajax on Hover?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a function in a wordpress site i'm working on at the moment, which has an interactive SVG map, If a specific country has anything linked to it (via posts2posts plugin) Then this is reflected on the map itself.

What i'm hoping to do is that if a user hovers over a section of the map, We could pull in the posts from that ID - if that makes sense?

So each section of the map has it's own ID with posts linked, I'm looking for a way i could query the posts under that ID, pull them in via ajax and display them to the user.

If anyone can point me in the right direction it'd be much appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at http://wp-api.org/#posts_retrieve-a-post . First you need to install it then you can use it.

Comment: You can use [wp_ajax](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_%28action%29) to query Wordpress via ajax. Also check out [AJAX in Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) for more resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hook [wp_ajax](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_%28action%29) is indeed what you are looking for. I created an (untested) example below. If you're going to use this, make sure to add nonces later on. A basic tutorial for WordPress, AJAX and noncens can be found [here](http://www.jackreichert.com/2013/03/24/using-ajax-in-wordpress-development-the-quickstart-guide/).

**mapinfo.js (in template directory)**

```
// Create variable
var mapID;

// Document ready
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

    // Hover over the element
    $('.map_section').mouseenter( function(){

        // Get hovered element map ID and save it in the mapID variable
        mapID = $(this).attr('ID');

        // JSON request: use the url from the localized script and use the get_map_info function. Both created in functions.php
        $.post( mapAjax.ajaxurl, {
            action: 'get_map_info',
            mapID: mapID
        }, function( response ) {

            // Turn the response into JSON variable called data
            var data = getJSON(response);

            /* Do whatever you want with the data here */
            $('#'+mapID).html(data.content);

            // Console.log the data for debugging
            console.log(data);

        });
    });

});
```

**functions.php**

```
// Localize the scripts so you have access to the AJAX variables in the front-end.
function enqueue_map_scripts(){

    // Enqueue your custom 'mapinfo.js' script
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mapinfo', get_template_directory_uri().'/mapinfo.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true );   

    // Localize this script to get the ajaxurl variable in the frontend
    wp_localize_script( 'mapinfo', 'mapAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_map_scripts' );

// The function for getting the map info
function get_map_info(){

    // Get the map ID from the AJAX-request
    $mapID = $_POST['mapID'];

    // Create an array to store the map information
    $mapInfo = array();

    // Get title, content and a meta field, add it to the mapInfo array
    $mapInfo['title'] = get_the_title( $mapID );
    $mapInfo['content'] = get_the_content( $mapID );
    $mapInfo['meta'] = get_post_meta( $mapID, '_example_meta_field', true );

    // Send JSON 
    echo json_encode($mapInfo); 

    // Die
    exit();

}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_map_info', 'get_map_info' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_map_info', 'get_map_info' );
```

Comment: Thanks Dave! This looks quite solid, Just about to give it a run and i'll report back and mark the reply as the answer should we be on the right track! :)